# Have php mail() function output to a local file instead of using SMTP

Tags: local, sendmail, php

I'd like to create an alternative sendmail.php file where instead of having to go through a server, a php mail() call gets appended to a local file, so that we can verify a mail() call is made and that it goes to the appropriate e-mail addresses.

I'm working on an installation of MAMP, but I think this could be applied across multiple local installations, and that's my hope - we've got all types of operating systems in my group.

This site:  http://www.drupal4hu.com/node/55makes me think it shouldn't be to difficult, but I think they were running the script from a live server, and it throws errors when I try it on my local machine.  The most frequent error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
```

doesn't seem relevant - some other obscure problem may have been causing that.

I'm  played around with editing the php.ini file, and I'm aware that I could direct everything through an SMTP server, but I'd rather not risk having someone (myself included) send e-mails to real people while we're testing.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a bunch of direct calls to the built-in `mail()`, you're unfortunately in a bad place.  The best solution is probably to create some wrapper, and quickly replace all bare calls to mail() with calls to your wrapper.

If that's somehow impossible, you could tweak the mail configuration to use a fake sendmail, of your own creation, which just writes stuff to disk.  You'd just set `mail.sendmail_path` to your fake-sendmail, and have that fake-sendmail do its thing.

But the best answer is to create an API for sending mail in your app, make sure it's always used, and the switch out back-ends from there.  Then when you want to ditch mail() for something like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html), you only need to change the implementation of your application-specific send_some_email() function.

Comment: How would I create such a fake sendmail that takes a set of parameters and writes them to disk?  I have a wrapper already, this is just for testing purposes (perhaps not the smoothest way to test but I'd prefer it to sending lots of real emails or creating a mail server on my computer)

Answer (score 1):

#### Update in year 2023:

I've been using https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog via docker for the past few years instead. It's actually much closer to the actual usage in production, where you usually send email using some STMP service like Mandrill, Mailgun or Sendgrid.

---

I've been using a simple script to pass the sendmail input to file:

```
# php.ini
sendmail_path = "c:\xampp-php7\sendmail.bat"
```

And the actual script ([gist](https://gist.github.com/tomasfejfar/0f73e9b5443960b79e55588b38a9ad31))

```
@echo off

::kam budeme ukládat e-maily?
SET mailpath=c:\temp\mail\

if not exist %mailpath% mkdir %mailpath%

::sestavíme název souboru
echo %date:~0,11%
SET filename=%date:~11,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~3,2%_%hours%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%_%time:~9,2%

::zajistíme unikátnost souboru
:random
SET file="%mailpath%%filename%--%RANDOM%.mhtml"
IF EXIST %file% goto :random

::e-mail uložíme do souboru
more %1 > %file%

echo "%file%" > c:\temp\list

::otevřeme adresář s e-maily Průzkumníkem
start %mailpath%

::a nebo přímo otevřeme e-mail
:: start %file%

echo "mail sent"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.

I tried and it is showing some unreadable multipart base64 code.
How to view it in pretty way?

Comment: Something like https://github.com/ayamadori/EmlReader ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the PHP `mail` function in development/testing, you should just have your system log the attempt and you can inspect your logs to verify that it is occurring.

Also, consider using something other than sendmail. SMTP libraries in PHP are everywhere, including ones that support full SSL and such (a la Gmail).